# Printing contents of cache register c7 in ARM926EJ

Tags: c, caching, assembly, inline-assembly, arm9

I'm trying to see the contents of cache register and the status of dirty bit in c7 before and after cleaning D cache.
This link:

https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0198/latest/programmers-model/register-descriptions/cache-operations-register-c7 says that "If the cache contains any dirty lines, bit 30 is set to 0. If the cache contains no dirty lines, bit 30 is set to 1." 
I have a variable c7Value initialized to 15(Random number)

```
"tc_loop:   \n"

    "MRC p15, 0, %[c7Value], c7, c10, 3             \n"     //Read value of c7 after cleaning

    "BNE tc_loop            \n"
    :[c7Value] "=r"(c7Value)

    );
```

When I print the value of c7Value after the above loop, the value comes out to zero. I thought that only the 30th bit will be set to 0, if it finds any cache line dirty.

Also, is there a way to just read the content of c7 without cleaning it?

Other registers like c1 can be read as :"MRC p15, 0, R1, c1, C0, 0", but there is no instruction to read c7.

Therefore, can someone please tell me know how to print the cache contents and/or read contents of c7(to check dirty status)?

Comment: Are you sure you don't dirty a line of cache before this code runs?  Compiler-generated code normally uses the stack.  If you compiled without optimization, it will almost certainly dirty the stack storing/reloading local variables.  Look at the compiler's asm output.

Comment: I have compiled without optimization. (Used volatile). But, firstly am I reading c7 correctly? Is the value 0 correct?

Comment: Without optimization you're probably dirtying the cache, so always seeing `0` is unsurprising based on what you say the instruction does.  IDK whether you're reading it correctly.  You've only shown a fragment, and I haven't looked up the docs for that instruction to see how it sets flags or anything.  It looks somewhat reasonable, but I'm not an ARM expert (just on x86, and GCC inline-asm syntax in general).  You might want a `"memory"` clobber to stop the compiler reordering loads/stores across it.

Comment: I must point out one thing about "reading the value of c7" comment. 
This will read the value of c7 after testing and cleaning the cache.